# Make a sql request faster

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got the following sql request and I wonder whether it's possible to make it work faster. What can I change here accelerate it a bit? It currently executes for 0.24 sec.

```
SELECT RECNO 
FROM ( SELECT T.ID, T.RECNO, T.STATE, T.TYPEID 
      FROM SOME_TABLE T 
      ORDER BY T.ID ) 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1 AND TYPEID = 123123 AND STATE = 123;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT RECNO 
FROM ( SELECT T.ID, T.RECNO, T.STATE, T.TYPEID 
       FROM SOME_TABLE T 
       where TYPEID = 123123 AND STATE = 123
       ORDER BY T.ID ) a
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OFFSET-FETCH` if you are using Oracle 12c+

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE T 
Where TYPEID = 123123 AND STATE = 123;
ORDER BY T.ID          
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY --OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Though am not very sure about the performance

Comment: But I think `ROWNUM`  is the column name.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @HamzaAnis - No its not a column present in your table. `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a table or set of joined rows. Check the link for more info https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Comment: @HamzaAnis No, it's the number of a record row